# postgres array field with select in condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a POSTGRES field with 2 fields - integer arrayfield and integer field.

```
CREATE TABLE test.public.polls (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    field_1 _int4,
    field_2 int4 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

and the values are

[image]

1) Now I need to check if any of the field value `{1,2,3}` is in the field_1

something like this -

```
select * from test.public.polls
where field_1 = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::int[])
```

but this throws an error

```
operator does not exist: integer[] = integer
```

2) Need to check if any of the id values = {2,3,4} is in the field_1

```
select * from test.public.polls
where field_1 = array(id)
```

not sure what should be the syntax for this.

Comment: Shouldn't `field_1` definition be `field_1 in4[]`?

Comment: either way a array field gets created.

Comment: Could you please clarify the questions? Does first question mean that you want to get records where arrays from `field_1` and `{1, 2, 3}` have any common elements? Does second question mean: get records where `field_1` array contains `id` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `field_1` seems to be an array then following should work (this is called [overlapping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)):

```
select *
from yourtable
where field_1 && '{1,2,3}'::int[]
```

For the second part it seems like you'd like to aggregate `id` column and check whether any value from the aggregated set exists within `field_1`:

```
select *
from yourtable
where field_1 && (select array_agg(id) from yourtable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [overlap operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) `&&`

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM polls
 WHERE '{1,2,3}' && field_1
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2876b/1)